# Controlar rele arduino desde python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en python, lo que hace es enviar un numero a arduino y arduino encender el rele o no. Pero no me funciona el if para encender el rele.

Arduino:

```
const int pinLED = 8;

 void setup() 
 {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);
  if (Serial.available()>0) 
  {
    char option = Serial.read();
  if (option = '1')
  {
    digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);

  }
 }
}
```

Python:

```
import serial, time
 arduino = serial.Serial("COM6", 9600)
 time.sleep(2)
 arduino.write(b'1')
 arduino.close()
```

Comment: Has hecho `if (option = '1')` en lugar de `if (option == '1')`. En todo caso, ese error debería hacer que la condición fuera cierta siempre, por lo que debería encenderte el LED. Quizás el fallo esté en otro lugar. ¿Tienes posibilidad de depurar lo que hace arduino? ¿Sabes si entra por el primer `if`?

Comment: Como puedo depurar el codigo en arduino?

Comment: No tengo experiencia en Arduino. En otras plataformas o bien tienes un depurador o bien puedes meter `printf() ` en diferentes partes del código para ver si pasa por ellas (verías los mensajes en la salida estándar). No sé si en arduino tienes `printf()` o equivalente, ni dónde verías la salida estándar, posiblemente en tu entorno de desarrollo. En una mala puedes meter instrucciones de encender un led cuando pase por ciertas líneas, para saber si las ejecuta. Pero si el problema está en el propio código de encender el led, esto no te ayudaría.

Comment: No se como depurar el codigo con el ide de arduino, no he logrado nada aun.

Comment: Mira [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225693/how-do-you-debug-arduino-code-running-on-arduino-hardware), especialmente la última respuesta que no requiere de ningún IDE en particular.

Comment: El IDE de aurduino te permite visualizar lo que escribes por el puerto serie. Es una forma de depurar lo que haces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes la linea `digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);` que enciende el rele en cada ciclo, aunque recibiera un 1 desde python en el ciclo siguiente se encendería de nuevo y no notarias que se apago.
Deberías cambiarla al setup si quieres que el led comience encendido.

```
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH); //<- Quita esta linea o cambiala al setup
    if (Serial.available()>0) 
    {
        char option = Serial.read();
        if (option == '1')//Tiene que ser == para comparar
        {
            digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```